# How to configure Hibernate ORM database properties to work with Docker

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, docker, docker-compose

In order to connect to the database I use a network socket, which is specified inside my `hibernate.cfg.xml` as:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:PORT/DBNAME</property>
```

along with username, password:

```
    <property name="connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pass</property>
```

I want to use docker for deployment.

My problem is that currently I have to change the source code (e.g hibernate.cfg.xml), and reproduce a new .war file, each time I want to re-deploy.

Is there a way to avoid this? Can I use the same .war file and link dynamically to a database from docker?

I suppose I could have a configuration file (something like .env) that would contain the db credentials and have both java and docker read this, but I don't now to configure docker to do so

Comment: What are you using for a Java EE server?

Comment: my stack is hibernate, postgresql, tomcat, nginx (as reverse proxy for tomcat)

Comment: Mainly my problem was that docker supports --env-file at docker run but not at docker build, but I ended up putting env variables inside dockerfile using ENV command (not the best practice). Thus combining this with andrepnh's response I suppose I can solve this issue.

Comment: There's a better solution - I just haven't had the time to present it. The trick is to set up a DataSource in JNDI in Tomcat and then access it with a JNDI lookup from Hibernate. Hibernate does the lifting for you here, you just need to specify the JNDI name in your hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out

Comment: @SteveC it could be done that way, but tomcat is inside a container. This means we're back on how to create the JNDI resource automatically for both dev, testing, production and any other environments.

Comment: @andrepnh, assuming the database is also a docker container, it's host name relative to the tomcat container can be a constant for all environments. You extend one of the existing standard Tomcat docker images and copy a prepared server.xml file into it's conf directory. I already do a similar thing with WildFly, although it's configuration is completely scriptable.

Comment: True, but my concern is mostly the different credentials and having to prepare multiple config files. In the end I still believe that environment variables, although not usual in Java EE, are much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have the following options:

- Use system properties in the XML as in `<property name="connection.username">${db.user}</property>`
- Maintain different `hibernate.cfg.xml` files using maven profiles and filters to pick the right one for each environment
- Use programmatic configuration and system properties or environment variables

The problem with system properties is that to use them you'll have to set them in your app server, use properties files or pass them through command line, as in `-Ddb.user=foo`. To set them in the app server, you'd have to make the container use a CLI, REST API, or maybe another configuration file (this time for the server) to set it up. It will depend on what you're deploying your `.war` to. Passing those properties through the command line has the problem of database credentials being there in plain text for anyone who can list that process.

Maintaining multiple configuration files, or using properties files is also a pain and it adds an overhead to your build process that I don't think it's necessary, at least not to set up simple credentials.

I believe you best bet is to use [programmatic configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic). Then all you'd have to do is set the right environment variables inside the container. In your application it would be just a matter of:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
    .setProperty("connection.username", System.getenv("DB_USER"))
    // ...
```